# How to get current time of playback in react-wavesurfer?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, wavesurfer.js

I need to get the current time of playback of an audio.
I've been using the [react-wavesurfer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-wavesurfe) package to play the audio and I can see that [wavesurfer.js](https://wavesurfer-js.org/docs/methods.html) has a method to get the current time of the playback but I can't seem to figure out how to do it with react.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-wavesurfer#onposchange-function

Answer (score 1):

Seems like they have `onPosChange` event in their [DOCS](https://github.com/mspae/react-wavesurfer#onposchange-function)

> Is basically called on audioprocess and seek events and consolidates
>   the received time formats into the same type of argument object as the
>   onAudioprocess callback (time in seconds, not as a relative value):

```
{   wavesurfer: wavesurferInstance,   originalArgs:
    [playBackPositionInSecs] 
}
```

It seems like it's the same as the "none-react" `audioprocess` [event](https://wavesurfer-js.org/docs/events.html):

Comment: `onPosChange` is indeed fired on `audioprocess`, but also when a `seek` event was fired. So it can be used to cache the current playback position (i.e. in component state)